# Normalizing rows/columns MATLAB without using loops

Tags: matlab, normalize

Can we use `bsxfun` to normalize all the rows and columns in matrix to a given norm so to avoid using loops? The Question concerns MATLAB.

What I do is :

```
   A   % I want to normalize rows in A
   norm_type = 1 ;   % or 2 or inf
   for i = 1 : size(A,1)
      tmp = norm(A(i,:),norm_type);
      A(i,:) = A(i,:)./tmp ;

   end
```

it would be nice to use an option without resorting to loops. Thanks

Comment: have you tried `normr`?

Comment: Yes you can but need to calculate `norm()` manually.

Comment: just google this question and you will find the solution... http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/normr.html

Comment: well, I think `normr` calculates the norm on each row which is nice but at the end you need to divide each row with that norm. Would be nice to do this without loop. Also I think, it does not allow different norm types by definition whereas `norm` does !

Comment: Sorry I was wrong about my first point. Still, I think this function does not allow different norm types.

Comment: I found a solution for my question, what do you think about it? This approach is very fast : %normalize each row norm 2:  `bsxfun(@times,A,1./sqrt(sum(A.*A,2)` %normalize each row norm 1:  `bsxfun(@times,A,1./sum(abs(A),2)` %normalize each row norm inf:  `bsxfun(@times,A,1./max(A,[],2)`

Comment: Answer your question and accept it.

Comment: Problem solved thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If the norm is 2-norm, then the following works:

```
A = diag(1./diag( sqrt(A*transpose(A)))) * A
```